# How to achive this design CSS

Tags: html, css

```
 Logo Here.                                   | --  3 Column -- |
               Error Message here             |                 |
____________________________________________ ||     W:232.5px   |
| - - 1 Column -- |     -- 2nd Column --     ||                 |
|    W:232.5px    |        W:465px           ||                 |
|_________________|__________________________||_________________|
 Max W: 930px.
```

Hey, could anyone explain to me how I can achieve this CSS.

3 columns, all has 100% height depending how much contents in the column, e.g. column 1 might be 
bigger than column 2 and/or 3.

I've also struggled to keep its structure when minimizing the browser, e.g column 3 is going under column 1.
so if possible I'd like to know how to keep its structure on minimizing.

Comment: Can you post the HTML/CSS you have tried?

Comment: What did try before? Have you wrote some code?

Comment: Can you post an image or a fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried using a framework for responsive design? Bootstrap and Fountation would be great tools to do what you want.

They both have a great grid system.

Comment: This isn't a code for me service.

Comment: image [link]http://oi61.tinypic.com/2uf3eo7.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe...

```css
body {
 border:0
 }
#logo {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 64px;
 background-color: blue;
 }
#error-msg {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 200px;
 width: 497px;
 height: 64px;
 background-color: green;
 }
#column1 {
 position: fixed;
 top: 64px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 232px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #efefaa;
 }
#column2 {
 position: fixed;
 top: 64px;
 left: 233px;
 width: 465px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #aaefef;
 }
#column3 {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 698px;
 width: 232px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #efaaef;
 }
```

```html
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="error-msg"></div>
<div id="column1"></div>
<div id="column2"></div>
<div id="column3"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to work, I haven't tested this on smaller screens, I hope it works! Thanks pal.

Comment: Do you know how to this make centered on the page?

Comment: To center those, you could add a DIV tag with ID="container" and put the above DIVs in the container div.  Set #container position: relative; height:100%; width: 933px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; and then change those DIV styles to use position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a Flexbox with align-items: flex-end;

That will align the items to the bottom of the container and respect their variable height and width.

[Here is a great reference for flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, you have just added a link to another website

Comment: @vihan1086 his question is essentially: "how do I have a 3 column layout where all the elements have variable width/height and are aligned to the bottom". Flexbox with align-items: flex-end; is the answer. That link is the best reference to flexbox (that I have found) on the internet and will do more for getting him started than any code snippet I could make for him.

Comment: @CarsonCrane I understand that that link might be helpful and would solve his problem but you should write your *own answer* instead of saying *"Use flexbox"* and then a link. Add your *own* complete answer. Links can die so future visitors will find your answer useless.

Comment: @user3127562 its HTML5 and works with all major browsers. [Here is the caniuse page for it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). If you need support for older browsers you can use it with the [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) Javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent column 3 go under column 1 either wrap everything inside a container with fixed width or use % as unit for the columns

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is pretty straight forward, you just need to add a wrapper to the first two columns and use that as the 'main' column.

In terms of responsiveness the best method is converting your pixels to percentage values, then using breakpoints when the widths start to become too tight/too wide.

```
 |________________________________________________| | --Side Column-- |
 |               - - Main Column - -              | |                 |
 |                     W: 75%                     | |                 |
 |________________________________________________| |                 | 
 | Logo Here.                                     | |                 |  
 |________________________________________________| |                 |
 |                Error Message here              | |                 |
 |________________________________________________| |                 |
 | ______________________________________________ | |       W:25%     |
 | | - - 1 Column -- |     -- 2nd Column --     | | |                 |
 | |      W:33.3%    |          W:66.6%         | | |                 |
 | |_________________|__________________________| | |_________________|
 |                                                | 
  ------------------------------------------------
```